# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null on export default function using react-scripts to compile

Tags: javascript, react-scripts

I'm facing a compilation issue, that I've managed to work-around somehow, but I'd like to understand where exactly is the problem coming from. Here is the issue:

I'm using react-create-app project to bootstrap a React project and I get the following error, at compilation time, with react-scripts (v3.1.1), when running `react-scripts start`:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/reducers/test.js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
```

The error occurs on the test.js file:

```
const initialArray = ['value1'];

export default function(inputArray = initialArray) {
  return [...inputArray, 'value2'];
};
```

After investigating, I've found this, more or less related problem, https://github.com/standard-things/esm/issues/434, of default exporting an anonymous function. Naming my function, solved the compilation problem

```
const initialArray = ['value1'];

export default function myFunc(inputArray = initialArray) {
  return [...inputArray, 'value2'];
};
```

*(a named export instead of the default export also solved the problem)*

But I've often exported anonymous functions by default, and I've never faced a compilation failure. And this is something I'm currently doing in other parts of my code, without experiencing a compilation failure from `react-scripts`.

So I also had a look at the input array used by the function. If I remove the spread operator to have a return line like this: `return ['value2'];`, it compiles, but the function's behaviour is altered. So I tried to change my default assignment to `inputArray` like this, and it compiled too:

```
const initialValue = 'value1';

export default function(inputArray = [initialValue]) {
  return [...inputArray, 'value2'];
};
```

But once again, I don't understand why my initial solution wouldn't compile. Do you see something I've been missing all along?

Thank you guys for your time!

Comment: did you check your package.json file to see if there ids a script associated with that command `react-scripts start`? also try installing NPM and running `npm start` from the folder of your project. does that work?

Comment: When I run `npm start`, it is actually `react-scripts start` command that gets executed, as defined in my package.json file. `react-scripts` command runs the js script that you can fine here @sao: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js which is kind of a blind spot for me, I admit.

Comment: very strange indeed. Thanks for pointing out how to solve that. I was stuck trying to find the root of the problem for an hour.

Comment: @RemiPrevost how did you solve this issue ?